# Uniqueness of Power Series for Sine?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm aware that there is only one power series representation for a function about a given center; however, based on [graphical evidence](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9bnbwzi9y7), it seems that both of these series converge to the sine function.
$$ \sin x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!} = \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}}_{\text{standard textbook def}}$$
May someone clue me in to what I might be missing here?

*Solved: The first series is not a power series.*

Comment: Put k=0 into the first term.

Comment: Yes, $(-1)!$ is undefined, but why then would the series appear to converge?

Comment: @clocktower: listen to Hamidine. A summation with an undefined term is undefined. And the remaining terms are exactly those of the second summation !

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see now...

Comment: Desmos is probably interpreting $\frac{1}{(-1)!}$ as zero, which is the natural thing to do for various reasons. Thus you're actually plotting the same function in each case anyway.

Comment: @clocktower $(-1)!$ is not undefined, it is defined as $\infty$. This causes the first term in the series to be $0$. You can safely write $\sin(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$.

Comment: @user647486 But, broadly, touching on the idea of uniqueness, the discrepancy is that the first series is not a power series, correct?

Comment: @clocktower Yes, power series is more often used when the powers are natural numbers. Take into account that this is only terminology, not content. Therefore, in some contexts some people could call it a power series. The uniqueness, on the other hand, is actual content, which holds even if you allow series with integer exponents. What it means is that the coefficients of the terms of the same degrees are equal. This is satisfied, as you can see.

Comment: @user647486: who said that the extended reals are allowed ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Which straw man are you trying to fight?